# Symfony 2 new Bootstrap form theme - file field type

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm using the [new Symfony Bootstrap form theme](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme), including this line in my view:

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
{{ form(form) }}
```

Everything displays fine, except for the files fields. The line for a file fields displays, from left to right:

- My custom label
- The word "File" **that's my problem**
- The "browse" button
- The name of the chosen file or the text "No file chosen"

I don't know where this word "File" comes from. On the screen-shot of the official page for this new functionality (cf link above), this word doesn't appear.
How can I remove it?

Comment: Can you post your form builder? I tried it, and I don't get the "File" word. Also maybe your browser is adding it?

Comment: @Konstantin Pereyaslov You made me have a better look at my form builder. I was using another form (ImageType) for my file:

Comment: @Konstantin Pereyaslov You made me have a better look at my form builder. I wasn't using directly the file filed type, but another form (ImageType):  `$builder->add('image1',      new ImageType())`  And in my ImageType class:  `$builder->add('file', 'file')`  .The first 'file' relates to an attribute of my Image Class, and since no label was specified for this sub-form field, Symfony made a default one: 'File'  Now I set `'label'` to `false`, the word File does not appear anymore but I have an ugly empty space instead. I'll try to solve this now! Thank you very much for your time and your help